# Delivery is delayed in exchange server 2007

Tags: exchange-2007

I have exchange server 2007 and everything is fine until I try to send attached file or simple email to another exchange server i got this message "delivery is delayed to these recipient" but if I try to send the same email from Hotmail or yahoo the email received.
Can any one help me.

Answer (score 1):

First question - is this a delay, or an error?

As in: Does the email finally go through after some time, or does it delay for some time, then fail?

Basically - obviously not everything is fine (your statement contradicts).

I would check SMTP protocols.

Somehow Hotmail, / Yahoo don't like your email.

There can be a *ton* of reasons for this, but we need to look deeper into your configuration.

- Is there a SPF record error; so not the domain?
- Are there any network routing problems?
- What about your SMTP host name and the reverse name on the IP you use - do they match?
- Is your server on a dynamic IP address?

All of those factors can contribute to a poor server sending reputation, and that leads to good servers not wanting to relay mail from you.